# Moving image from one file to another in Gimp

Tags: images, gimp

I’m trying to move an image I have selected and put on a transparent background.  Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when I try:
[image]
The selected image disappears and I can't find it anywhere.  Have tried many different "HOW Tos" on the net to no avail.  If you can tell me, PLEASE don't leave out a simple step!  I take the move tool making sure it is set to move the selected layer, and drag the image over to the new file............it disappears as it is leaving the first file, how do you keep that from happening?  Been using Gimp for years after I couldn’t afford Photoshop.  Usually takes me forever to learn a new trick!  Funny how easy it is after you get the missing part of the instructions!

Answer (score 1):

The move tool won't move a layer between images, you are just moving the layer outside the bound of the canvas (as you can see with the mayer boundaries) If you want to move a layer between two images, then:

1. select the source image
2. open the Layers list (ctrl-L)
3. click on the layer that you want to move in that list
4. drag it to the target image

Note that it won't be a move but a copy (layer still exists in the source image).

Answer (score 0):

Select layer, or layers, you want to save and then right click go to Edit -> Copy to clipboard.

Then go up to File -> Create -> from cllipboard and there you go.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).